# Looking for a formula to calculate maximun number of combination with restrictions

Tags: statistics, combinations, programming

I have this problem.

I want to select 40 numbers out of 120 and create all possible subsets, however there is a restriction that each subset is at least 50% different than the all other ones (or if it makes it simpler it is exactly 50% different than all other subsets).  Numbers can not reappear/repeat in the same subset, the order of appearance in a subset is not important.

Is there a math or stats formula or programming code that can calculate this?

Comment: Well, you can rule out brute-force, unless you have a computer powerful enough to generate all 114,556,848,244,965,165,743,109,806,892,471 combinations of 40 numbers.

Comment: If there's something you want to do the subsets (mean, proportion of numbers below 7, etc.), then you don't have to create all zillion possible subsets.